# What is the source of sunnah.com while grade the hadith given in collections other than Bukhari and Muslim?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

What is the source of [sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com) while grade the hadith given in collections other than Bukhari and Muslim ?

For example, [this](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/41/40) hadith says its **da'if (Darussalam)**. Which scholar's grading scheme are they using ? I think for Abu Dawood, they specifically mention **Sheikh Albani**, but not for any other collections.

Answer (score 3):

I found out [here](http://sunnah.com/about) that when they mention Darussalam, they mean **Zubair Ali Zai**